# Utf 8 in webmin

Tags: webmin

I am trying to run scripts via webmin but I am getting utf issues.

The error is as follows:

```
stdout encoding 'ascii' detected. googler requires utf-8 to work properly. The wrong encoding may be due to a non-UTF-8 locale or an improper PYTHONIOENCODING. (For the record, your locale language is <unknown> and locale encoding is <unknown>; your PYTHONIOENCODING is not set.)

Please set a UTF-8 locale (e.g., en_US.UTF-8) or set PYTHONIOENCODING to utf-8.
```

I converted the `iso8859` to EN. `utf-8` in webmin lang folder. Webmin language Configuration does not show the utf8 file.
Is there any way I can run utf-8 in webmin?

Thank you.

Comment: Can any one please share light on this issue?

Comment: Type `locale` at your consolle share the output